# Parallelizing a small array is slower than parallelizing a large array?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, icc

I wrote a small program that generates random values for two valarrays and in a for loop the values of said arrays are added to a new one.

However, when I use a small array size(20 elements) the parallel version takes significantly longer than the serial one and when I'm using large arrays(200 000 elements) it takes roughly the same amount of time(parallel is always a bit slower though).

Why is this? 
The only reason I can think is that with the large array the CPU puts it in L3 cache and shares it across all cores, whereas with the small one its having to copy it around the lower cache levels? Or I'm getting this wrong?

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int size = 2000000;
    std::valarray<double> num1(size), num2(size), result(size);
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, stop;
    std::chrono::microseconds duration;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
     num1[i] = std::rand();
     num2[i] = std::rand();
    }

    //Parallel execution
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];
    }
    stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Parallel for loop executed in: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    //Serial execution
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];
    }
    stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Serial for loop executed in: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

Output with `size = 200 000`

```
Parallel for loop executed in: 2450 microseconds
Serial for loop executed in: 2726 microseconds
```

Output with `size = 20`

```
Parallel for loop executed in: 4727 microseconds
Serial for loop executed in: 0 microseconds
```

I'm using a Xeon E3-1230 V5 and I'm compiling with Intel's compiler using maximum optimization and Skylake specific optimizations as well.

I get identical results with Visual Studio's C++ compiler.

Comment: Regarding `srand`, you may want to watch [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Factors that effect this: there's a lot of overhead in starting a thread, so small values of `size` will run faster on one thread; your loop performance is memory bound, and unlikely to improve with more than 2 threads; small values of `size` may result in several of your 8 threads writing to the same cache line.

Comment: BTW, there is no guarantee that threads will run on separate cores.  Worst case, they are scheduled on the same core.

Comment: Optimizations don't always improve the speed of code. That's why they have to be manually enabled. That could be part of the problem.

Comment: Also, just as a note, using simd would also be useful here since your code could be easily vectorized. You should see some speedup regardless of the issue you have.